# How to increase the speed of the following slide animation?

Tags: javascript, animation

The following slide animation has inertia: the slide animation keeps going and then the speed decreases slowly over time. When `interval` reaches `100`, the animation stops.

```
let interval = 1 // initial speed
const timer = function () {
  ++interval // decrease the speed
  slideThumbs(thumbs, direction) // do the sliding animation
  const timeOut = setTimeout(timer, interval)
  // stop animation when the speed reaches 100
  if (interval === 100) {
    clearTimeout(timeOut)
  }
}
timer()
```

It works. But it's extremely slow. How can I increase the overall speed? (From the initial sliding to when the animation stops?)

**EDIT:**

This is what's inside `slideThumbs`:

```
const totalThumbs = newChildrenArr.length
const thumbWidth = 144 // thumb width plus margin
const slideLimit = (totalThumbs - 1) * thumbWidth
if (arrow === 'left') {
  store.state.translateX += 1 // add one pixel to the `transform: translateX` attribute
}
```

Comment: When you initially do `setTimeout(timer, interval)` you are firing it after 1 millisec, this quickly becomes 2, then 3, and so on, for every milisec that passes the number value raises. It takes it 2 milisec to fire a second time, 5 milisecs to fire it 3rd time, 8 milisecs to fire 4 times and so on. By the time you reach 0.5 seconds, you fired it 30 times, which is okay, that is close to 60 FPS. Now, for next half a second, you only fire it 13 times. which is less then half of the initial count. This goes on.

Comment: Instead, I suggest you keep the function flying on the same interval, with `setInterval(function, interval)` and instead decrease the "travel distance" of the object per function execution.

Comment: usually I would recommend to google for `Tweening` and `easing`-function, but I had a blink on your post this morning. I don't know wether a different approach wouldn't be better. please show/explain more of the context to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The ++interval will increase the value of the interval. So the interval is increasing and slowing the animation.

Only thing I'd suggest is to decrease the delta between each call to a smaller value and reduce the interval from 100.

Also look into doing some performance analysis of the slideThumbs method - it might be this that is causing the overhead, but without seeing the code it's difficult to test.

(Edit - got the code now on the question). How much time does the transform take? I'd suggest it might be this which is causing the poor performance as it'll be executed a lot in this case.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wcbswvks/) is an JSFiddle example of how I'd do what I said in the comments

```
 function ClosureWrapper(callback) {
  var distance = 50;
  var timer = Trigger;

  function Trigger() {
    if (distance <= 0) {
      callback();
    } else {
      distance--;
      //do something
      console.log("distance moved this interval is: " + distance);
    }
  }
  return timer;
}

var someTimer = setInterval(ClosureWrapper(function() {
  console.log("Movement Finished")
  clearInterval(someTimer);
}), 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I tried it, and the slider goes at the same speed all the time (1px) and and then it stops.

Comment: Code your slide in the `//do something` part. As you can see the "distance parameter" decreases there, so if you code the slider with it, it will HAVE to move slower, or your slider movement code is wrong. `ctrl+shift+i` and check the console log, you will see that distance gets reduced with every run.